# Why does matlab show r squared for non-linear

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting

Inspired by the comments here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27288483/python-multiple-curve-fitting-models

In matlab, why is the R squared value displayed if it is meaningless for non-linear equations?

Is there a different use for it than those comments suggest?

This is the comment:

> R.sq is meaningless for non-linear models. For linear models, R.sq is
>   the fraction of variability explained by the model. For non-linear
>   models this is not the case. Within a family (say, polynomials),
>   models with more parameters will always produce larger R.sq, so this
>   metric is useless to assess goodness of fit

Answer (score 2):

$R^2$ is a good measure of explained variance in both linear and nonlinear models. It has its issues, such as not being between 0 and 1, but it's still useful.

> A minor problem can arise in evaluating the fit of the regression in
>   that the familiar measure, 
>   $R^2 = 1 − \frac{\sum_{i=1}^ne^2_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n(y_i-\bar{y})^2}$ ,
>   (7-17) is no longer guaranteed to be in the range of 0 to 1. It does,
>   however, provide a useful descriptive measure.

Greene,William H., Econometric analysis, 7th ed., 2012

Comment: In fitting very nonlinear models, such as those with strange attractors, I can even think of an example where optimizing $R^2$ was the objective function. Courtney Brown, Serpents in the Sand, 1995. I believe it's the ecology and policy section, but I can't recall precisely.

Comment: $R^2$ works just fine in [your example](http://www.courtneybrown.com/publications/SerpentsInTheSandByCourtneyBrown.pdf), as they've been optimizing the parameters, and not selecting the models.